# Execute jar file main from java class with parameters

Tags: java, jar

I have an executable jar with the package.mainclass Parm1 Parm2 Parm3 Parm4 Parm5

```
inputFileEdit.InputFileTest parm1 parm2 parm3 parm4 parm5
```

I would like to run the jar (farEditCheck2.jar) within my java class with a return so I can determine my next action within the class.

My jar has been added to my workpath, and I have been able to import my class `import inputFileEdit.*;`

Is there a way to call the main class with a return?

Comment: Is decompiling the jar an option?

Comment: Not too sure, but a process don't have a return parameter far beyond the exit code. Once started, farEditCheck2.jar will run independently, but you could communicate them with a net communication.

Comment: Can you edit the jar to run the code you want to run when the executable jar is called?

Comment: I figured out what to do, but it doesn't answer my initial question.   I created another class without a main and called it normally. That worked.